# Busy Indicator not able to lock Screen in Eclipse JUNO(4.2)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have an eclipse plugin in which I have used the Busy Indicator while showing progress and it locks the UI in all other eclipse to restrict the user to perform any clicks on the UI but it is not able to lock the screen in Eclipse JUNO and I am able to perform multiple clicks while one job is in progress. Please suggest whether it is a bug in eclipse 4.2 release or there is any problem in my the code that I have written.

[image]

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: BusyIndicator.showWhile(Display.getCurrent(), new Runnable()
     {
      public void run()
      {
          //Here goes my processing code
      }
     });

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Possibly you are doing something in your 'processing code' which is driving the SWT message loop. Edit your question and show us a minimal version of the code.